# opp_run error on omnetpp IDE

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm working on a veins project at the moment and everything went fine till today.
I had the need to add a new module to the ' veins/src/veins/modules ' directory so I simply created a new folder and put some .ned files and relative header/source files in there. I got some errors after doing that but nothing special (I was probably doing something wrong and compiler didn't like it). I then decided to delete the folder and try again maybe the day after.

After doing so I re-run the same exact simulation and omnet/IDE started showing this, not being able to launch:

```
<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.so': ../../src//libveins.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8Flooding6finishEv

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
```

I've tryed a fresh clean and rebuilt the whole veins project but that didn't help.
I googled this error but couldn't find anything similiar to my case.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Try to delete libveins.so by hand and rebuild project.

Comment: When you Clean Local -> Clean Project -> Rebuild it automatically deletes the libveins.so file so I doubt that's the matter but I'll try.

Comment: Do you still have some code that is pointing to the symbols you created? I don't think the `_ZN8Flooding6finishEv` symbol is part of VEINS. If all else fails, try cloning a fresh copy of VEINS and compiling that -- if that works, `git bisect` on the commit history of your project to find the commit that introduced the error.

Comment: `c++filt _ZN8Flooding6finishEv` shows that the missing symbol is `Flooding::finish()`. It seems that you have a deceleration of this method but missing a corresponding implementation. I'd assume your module was called `Flooding` and you did not delete all of it when starting over.

Comment: Oh I found out by myself what the problem was but It's exactly as you said. I just couldn't figure out what that undefined symbol ment. Running the same configuration on Windows showed that it was indeed `Flooding::finish()` not implemented (that's probably because it's automatically demangled on Windows). It's just weird that's been told by the opp_run and not the compiler. Anyways, all good now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are very welcome to add an answer to your (own) question. This will allow other users who  ignite have a similar problem in the future to easily find the question (and the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> c++filt _ZN8Flooding6finishEv shows that the missing symbol is
>   Flooding::finish(). It seems that you have a deceleration of this
>   method but missing a corresponding implementation. I'd assume your
>   module was called Flooding and you did not delete all of it when
>   starting over.
>
> ## Julian Heinovski

Running the same configuration on Windows showed that it was indeed Flooding::finish() not implemented (that's probably because it's automatically demangled on Windows). I just deleted the declaration and solved my little inattention.

Comment: Thanks for citing :)