# Can't launch Artery example

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I have compiled veins, vanetza, inet and artery but I'm not able to launch the Artery example. Under the Artery root directory, I did the following:

```
cd build make run_example
```

The following error happens:

```
<!> Error: Cannot load library '/home/renault/artery/build/src/artery/envmod/libartery_envmod.so': /usr/local/lib/libvanetza_security.so: undefined symbol: _ZN8CryptoPP10RandomPool34GenerateIntoBufferedTransformationERNS_22BufferedTransformationERKSsy

End.
scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example' failed
make[3]: *** [scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:644: recipe for target 'scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:651: recipe for target 'scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [scenarios/artery/CMakeFiles/run_example.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:274: recipe for target 'run_example' failed
make: *** [run_example] Error 2
```

I'm on ubuntu with crypto++ 5.6.1 installed

Thanks

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that the given symbol could not be found. Using `c++filt`, you can find out that the symbol is the following:

```
CryptoPP::RandomPool::GenerateIntoBufferedTransformation(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long long)
```

This could indicate that you declared this method somewhere - probably in a header file - but did not provide an implementation for it (in the corresponding `.cc` file).

See also:

- [opp_run error on omnetpp IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458336/opp-run-error-on-omnetpp-ide/50483741#50483741)
- [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12573818#12573818)

Comment: Thanks. will try and let you know

Comment: to fix this issue, I have to compile libcrypto library with the same g++ version as the one used to compile my code.